# How to add custom loader instead of the pacman loader in jhipster project

Tags: angular, jhipster

I would like to add custom loader for jhipster initial page.right now which is loading the dafault packman loader of jhipster application.
please help me,thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Edit `src/main/webapp/content/css/loading.css` file to fit your needs.